# TeamCity "Changes" page

Tags: svn, version-control, teamcity

I have TeamCity connected to Subversion. It is building for scheduled triggers but not for VCS triggers. I think I tampered with the VCS username settings.

What name should be in the VCS username settings page?

It shows nothing in the "Changes" page which is right to the "Projects" page.

Normal build run is happening but VCS triggers are not happening. I'm not using a custom path for checkout.

Comment: When your scheduled build runs, does it successfully check the code out from SVN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your VCS settings are most likely not setup correctly. You need a username/password that has basically full permissions to the VCS. There is also a "Test Connection" button - I'm assuming that fails.

[Here](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD7/Subversion) are instructions to setup SVN as a VCS root. Be sure to follow these.